# Google Sign-in: how to avoid popup dialog if user is already signed in by using listeners?

Tags: javascript, user-experience, google-oauth, google-signin

Right now I'm using `auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {}, onSuccess, onError);`.  It works, but if I've already signed in, the dialog box opens and closes right away which is rather ugly.  Is there a way around this [using listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners)?

I played around the example but I'm not sure if listening for changes to current user is all I need, and my check of `googleUser` seems risky.

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({client_id: 'xxxxx'});
auth2.currentUser.listen(function (user) {
      googleUser = user;
      if (typeof(googleUser.getBasicProfile()) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('signupAsGoogle').addEventHandler('click', popuplateForm);
      else
        auth2.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById('signupAsGoogle'), {}, onSuccess, onError);
```

Is there a better way? Thanks

Comment: perhaps you could set a cookie in your local domain and validate against your own server once you have an authenticated session?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the same problem!

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    clientid: '${clientId}',
    cookiepolicy: '${cookie_policy}',
});

auth2.currentUser.listen(function (googleUser) {
    if (googleUser.isSignedIn()) {
        // do your login(googleUser) function
    } else {
        auth2.attachClickHandler("your button", {},
            function (googleUser) {
                // do your login(googleUser) function
            }, function (error) {
            });
    }
});
```